# Prevent PHPMailer email going to Hotmail Junk Folder

Tags: php, email, spf

I have created a mailing software using PHPmailer. Everything is working ok apart from emails are going to Hotmail junk folder. Yahoo, Gmail, Aol and other domains are receiving the emails but not Hotmail.

I have set SPF on my hosting for the domain which I am sending the email from and When I check the source of the email on Hotmail, it shows this:

```
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass.
```

The emails I am sending is not classified as spam as I get it checked with some online tools. I also tried sending test emails as if I am sending an email to a friend. Still no luck

Has anyona any idea if there is anything else I should do?

Note1:I have checked other posts on here but I couldnt find an answer so I am posting my own with my own details.

Note2: I have also tried sending Gmail SMTP and still emails are going to junk folder.

Note3: I have also tried the hosting company email domain to send but still it goes into junk mail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Junk mail is a very difficult matter and there might be not a simple answer to your question. There are several ways in which you could enhance your chances of being recieved in the regular inbox, but nothing is a guarantee. Possible technical solutions are to implement spf, dkim (thus dmarc). Other solutions may include changing your e-mail design and content (picture to text ratio, bold to non-bold ratio, title to non-title ratio, common spam keywords, removing unnecessary links and so on). It is hence almost impossible to pinpoint this behavior to one cause.

Comment: Unfortunately Hotmail's filtering is inept at best, and it's very difficult to deliver anything there, even with perfect SPF, DKIM & DMARC records in place and zero spam ever sent from the domain. They impose delivery rate limits, and block you outright if you exceed them - but don't tell you what the limits are!

Comment: Thank you for comment. All of those you said were taken into consideration. Because of that I wanted to make sure by sending email from the hosting company's own email client which is webmail.1and1.co.uk but it still went to junk.

Answer (score 1):

Take a good look at the email headers on the receiving hotmail account. There will be clues as to why you're email is being classified as junk.

Take a look at this article.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205071(v=exchg.150).aspx

You're looking for two header fields called

```
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report
X-Microsoft-Antispam
```

You're going to see a BCL, PCL, SRV with a colon after it and a value, depends on what those values are will be your clues as to why you're hitting the spam folder.

Without posting the full header, their's little information anyone is going provide other then telling you to try this and that. I'm a big proponent of telling people to use this [mail tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/), because it's the best around, but no mail testing program is going to solve every problem, but they are a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that mailtester that looks pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

Getting around email spam filters (as a legitimate sender) is a complicated issue.

Personally I recommend using [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/), [Sparkpost](https://www.sparkpost.com/), or another [email service](https://zapier.com/learn/ultimate-guide-to-email-marketing-apps/best-transactional-email-sending-services/).

These guarantee delivery and most are free for the scale you'll be operating at. I personally recommend mailgun.